# What javascript RegEx will match all instances of my mergefields?

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx pattern to match any/all instances that look like {!(.*)}

I have tried the following:
ie.
var mergefield_array = value.match(patt);

where value = '{!lat},{!lng}'
and patt = /{!(.*)}/

it returns a single result:  {!lat},{!lng}
but I want it to return two matches in this case ('{!lat}' and '{!lng}').

How do I do it?

Colin G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex is greedy in nature due to use of `.*` hence matching first `{` to last `}`, grabbing anything on the way.

To fix you can make it non-greedy:

```
patt = /{!(.*?)}/g
```

Or use negation:

```
patt = /{!([^}]*)}/g
```

Comment: The `g` modifier is missing. Without it will only return the first match and not all (both) as requested.

Comment: Thanks very much! I see both work - is there any reason to choose one over the other?